# Fitting a big grid (wxGrid) in a dialog (wxDialog)

Tags: c++, user-interface, layout, wxwidgets, sizer

Here is my layout:

- I have a sizer that contains a grid (with a proportion of 1) and a ok/cancel button bar
- The all thing is in a wxDialog

Here it is:

```
|||||||||||||||
|             |
|    GRID     |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|||||||||||||||
| OK  CANCEL  |
|||||||||||||||
```

The issue is that the grid contains too many row, and over flow the screen, so in the end I don't see the top part of the dialog. Is there a way, when calling Fit() on the dialog, to limit its height ?

I have tried stuff like this: `SetSizeHints(-1,-1,-1,500);` and `SetMaxSize(500,500)` but it did not worked.

Also I have tried to do that: `this->SetSize(this->GetSize().GetX(), 500);`, but since the vertical scroll bar appears on the grid, it is not wide enough and a horizontal scroll bar shows up.

**EDIT**

In the constructor I call `wxGrid(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize)`

Comment: Please post the code.  Are you setting the size of the grid in the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is to use a grid of fixed size.  If there are more rows than will fit, then a scroll bar will appear.  You set the size you want in the constructor.

```
new wxGrid( this, IDC_grid, wxPoint(-1,-1),wxSize(igridxsize,igridysize));
```

If you want the size of the grid to adjust, e.g. when the user resizes the application window, things are a bit more complex.  You need handle the window size event and change the grid size as appropriate.

Something along these lines:

```
myDialog::OnSize(wxSizeEvent& event);
{
wxSize dialogSize = event.GetSize();
myGrid->OnSize( wxSizeEvent(
     dialogSize.GetWidth() * 0.9, dialogSize.GetHeight() * 0.7 ));
}
```

Comment: Great, so I chose the option where the grid has a fix size, and it does the job. Thanks.