# wxWidgets fitting big wxGrid in wxFlexGridSizer

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, sizer, wxgrid

### Problem

I have a `wxGrid` with many rows (>200) placed inside a `wxFlexGridSizer`. The problem is that my button below the grid disappears. Same thing with a `wxBoxSizer` works using the **proportion** setting.

The result *should* look like the wxBoxSizer solution.
Is there a way to use a `wxFlexGridSizer` in such situation?

### wxBoxSizer (working)

[image: wxBoxSizer ScreenShot]

```cpp
    wxGrid *grid = new wxGrid(this, wxID_ANY);
    grid->CreateGrid(0, 2);
    grid->SetDefaultRowSize(20);
    grid->AppendRows(200);

    wxButton *button = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "button");

    wxBoxSizer *bsMain = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    bsMain->Add(grid, 1, wxALL, 5);
    bsMain->Add(button, 0, wxALL, 5);

    SetSizer(bsMain);
```

### wxGridSizer (not working)

[image: wxFlexGridSizer Screenshot]

```cpp
    wxGrid *grid = new wxGrid(this, wxID_ANY);
    grid->CreateGrid(0, 2);
    grid->SetDefaultRowSize(20);
    grid->AppendRows(200);

    wxButton *button = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "button");

    wxFlexGridSizer *fgsMain = new wxFlexGridSizer(1, 0, 0);
    fgsMain->Add(grid, 1, wxALL, 5);
    fgsMain->Add(button, 0, wxALL, 5);
    fgsMain->AddGrowableRow(0);
    fgsMain->AddGrowableCol(0);

    SetSizer(fgsMain);
```

I tried to use `AddGrowableRow` for both rows, proportion setting, `wxEXPAND` flag.

There is a similar question here, but the solution is a workaround:

[Fitting a big grid (wxGrid) in a dialog (wxDialog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070430/fitting-a-big-grid-wxgrid-in-a-dialog-wxdialog)

(Screenshoots are made with `wxFormBuilder v3.8.1`)

Comment: You don't set an initial size for the grid nor the button. Try that workaround (set at least minimal sizes) at don't forget `Layout()` or `SetSizerAndFit(...)`

Comment: Both commands does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `wxGrid` will try to show all of its 200 rows on screen, which won't leave enough place for the button. You may call `SetInitialSize()` (or specify the initial size when creating the grid in its ctor) to change this.

Unrelated to this question, but I strongly advise you to use more readable `wxSizerFlags`-based API rather than the old `Add()` overloads. You also shouldn't hardcode the border size in pixels, this is always wrong for some platforms and gets even worse on high DPI displays (and using `wxSizerFlags` would have taken care of this automatically).

Comment: `SetInitialSize()` doesn't change anything. I tried it for both (the button and the grid).
Thank you for the hint with `wxSizerFlags` I never heard off before.